# Can a cyclic quadrilateral be inscribed in a parabola?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

It is quite obvious that a quadrilateral can be inscribed in a parabola. However, can somebody provide a *nice* (meaning: *intuitive*) proof that a cyclic quadrilateral can be inscribed in it?

Further, if you can prove that it is possible to have an inscribed quadrilateral such that the diagonals are equal, then it'd be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a parabola, zoom out until it looks really thin, then draw a circle through it. Note that the two figures intersect in four points.

...Equal diagonals? Sure, just center the circle on the parabola's axis of symmetry!

Comment: Thanks. But there is one more part to the question I quite forgot to ask. Editing the question. (Really sorry if this kinda thing annoys you, but I - quite dumbly - forgot to ask the 2nd part)

Comment: @ParthThakkar No prob!

Answer (score 3):

Sure, one such example might be

\begin{align}
x^2-y &= 0 \\
x^2+(y-13)^2 &= 25
\end{align}

with the intersection points being $(\pm 3, 9)$ and $(\pm 4, 16)$.

Picture courtesy of [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dx%5E2%2C+x%5E2%2B%28y-13%29%5E2+%3D+25):

[image: a]

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Hey! This is cool. Really. I've been working all the problems, but most of them never a give a real 'feel' of the conic. This example does. +1 :D

Comment: @ParthThakkar The miraculous power of examples $\ddot\smile$